# Date Picker Only Works After Clicking out of Text Field

Tags: swift, uidatepicker

I have a date picker I am using to set the value of a text field. It works great except that it only works the 2nd time that I tap into the text field, that is, the first time I tap the text field it shows me the standard keyboard. Then if I tap out of the textfield and back into it, it shows the datepicker. I've tried different variations of it, but it either doesn't work at all, or I get the same problem. This is how I set it up:

```
class ExpDateTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!


@IBAction func textFieldEditing(sender: UITextField) {

    let datePickerView:UIDatePicker! = UIDatePicker()

    datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.date

    sender.inputView = datePickerView

    datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ExpDateTableViewCell.datePickerValueChanged), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
}

func datePickerValueChanged(sender:UIDatePicker) {

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

    dateFormatter.dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.medium

    dateFormatter.timeStyle = DateFormatter.Style.none
    textField.text = dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)


}


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

}
```

Comment: must you use a textfield? can't you replace it with a label or button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this code:

```
@IBAction func textFieldEditing(sender: UITextField) {
    // ...
    sender.inputView = datePickerView
}
```

You are not setting the text field's `inputView` to the picker view until *after* the first time we have started editing. Thus we get the effect you correctly described: the *second* time we edit, the picker view is present.

You need to set the text field's `inputView` much earlier, such as in `awakeFromNib`, *before* the user has a chance to edit the text field for the first time.

Comment: Thank you very much, Matt. That makes a lot of sense. However, can you tell me how I can reference  "datePickerView" from outside the function... since it is being declared inside the function

Comment: Obviously the point is that you have to move _all_ the code that configures the text field's `inputView` to some earlier point in time.

Answer (score 0):

First make UIDatepickerview as a inputview for textfield

Add this code inside the textfield action

```
@IBAction func textFieldEditing(sender: UITextField) {
let datePickerView:UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date
sender.inputView = datePickerView
datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.datePickerValueChanged), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
```

}